# Does fgets store a newline or just \0?

Tags: c

I am confused. Over the internet you can see different answer, so what is the real answer? Thanks.

What will be stored in name?
Assume the user types the following:

JennyENTER

20ENTER

```
void function()
{
    int product;
    
    char name[10];
    
    fgets(name, 10, stdin);
    
    scanf("%d", &product);  
}
```

A. Jenny\0

B. Jenny\n\0

Comment: When the input is short enough to fit, the newline will be included.  If the data before the newline is 9 characters or more (for the code above), the newline will not be included and the extra characters and newline will be left in the input stream to be read by another input call.  If you enter `Jenny` (and a newline), the newline will be included.  If you enter `Jennifer`, you also get the newline, but if you enter `Stephanie` and a newline, you don't get a newline.

Comment: Lesson: *Don't Skimp On Buffer Size!* Rule of thumb when not on a micro-controller, take your longest anticipated input and double it for the buffer size. For general line input a 1K or 2K buffer is fine. Names 128 bytes are generally fine, etc...`name[strcspn (name, "\n")] = 0;` will trim the `'\n'` from the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the input is short enough to fit, the newline will be included.

If the data before the newline is 9 characters or more (for the code above), the newline will not be included and the extra characters and newline will be left in the input stream to be read by another input call.  If you enter `Jenny` (and a newline), the newline will be included.  If you enter `Jennifer`, you also get the newline, but if you enter `Stephanie` and a newline, you don't get the newline (it's left behind to be read by another input function).  If you enter `Antidisestablishmentarianism`, you get the input string `Antidises\0`, and `tablishmentarianism` is left for other input code to read.

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out this small program.

When running, give inputs with length greater than 10 and less than 10.
You see that a new line (10)dec will be stored before storing `\0` if input length is less than 10.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[10] = {0};
    int i  = 0;
    fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin);
    
    while(str[i])
    {
        printf("%d %d = %c\n" ,i, str[i], str[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d %d = %c\n" , i, str[i], str[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLM                                                                                                         
0 65 = A                                                                                                              
1 66 = B                                                                                                              
2 67 = C                                                                                                              
3 68 = D                                                                                                              
4 69 = E                                                                                                              
5 70 = F                                                                                                              
6 71 = G                                                                                                              
7 72 = H                                                                                                              
8 73 = I                                                                                                              
9 0 =
```

```
HELLO                                                                                                                 
0 72 = H                                                                                                              
1 69 = E                                                                                                              
2 76 = L                                                                                                              
3 76 = L                                                                                                              
4 79 = O                                                                                                              
5 10 =                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                      
6 0 =
```